# Can we use 'this' pointer inside constructor

Tags: c++, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ using this pointer in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516960/c-using-this-pointer-in-constructors)

Like the title, may I do something like the following code?

```
class A;

class B {
public:
    B(A* p);
    ...
};

class A {
    B m;
public:
    A():m(this){}
    ~A(){}
};
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: There is a difference in passing a this pointer to the c'tor of a member or passing a this pointer to a different thread. In the first case, one can easily control when the object under construction is accessed the first time, for the second, it's at least all but simple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can passed a pointer to an object currently under construction. But you have to keep in mind, that the object isn't constructed completely yet. So basically what B can do in it's c'tor is store the pointer for later use.

An example where this is often used, is a std::stream and a stream buffer.